# How to publish a WinUI3 project as an exe file?

Tags: exe, publish, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I have created a WinUI 3 project and finished coding. I want to publish my app as an exe file(It is not necessary to have only one file, there can be many library files). I have searched on the Internet and I found one way. I tried to make the project unpackaged and I added

```xml
<WindowsPackageType>None</WindowsPackageType>
<WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>true</WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>
```

to csproj file.

It stands to reason that it should be useful. But in fact, it reported an error——"You must deploy before you can debug"(Probably written like this), But I've opened the deployment.

How can I resolve this error, or is there another way to solve my problem?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app should run by clicking the *.exe file. But to debug your app, you need to launch it as an *Unpackaged* app. Check image in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/create-your-first-winui3-app#:%7E:text=C%23.%20To,Windows%20File%20Explorer.).

Comment: I have this [video](https://youtu.be/CotNgFCnoj4?si=lOHb6eNgtdeKyHjv) if you want to see it in action.

Comment: Thanks for your answer very much. I have successfully run my app in Visual Studio in unpackaged mode following your method. But how do I package it? If I use publishing, double-clicking on the generated exe file doesn't work, if I use packaging, I only get an msix file, and installing it on the client requires an installation certificate, which is too much trouble

Comment: And Also, how can I use "ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride" in unpackaged app? I want to use .resw files to implement multilingual mode. When the user needs to switch languages, I need to switch the app language, but this API is not supported in unpackaged applications

Comment: Thanks for your video. I can run the exe file now in unpackaged mode. The only problem now is how to automatically change the language using rew files. In unpackaged mode, the API which can change the language of the app is not supported!

Comment: `PrimaryLanguageOverride` is for packaged apps. Check this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/1687). You could try my NuGet package [WinUI3Localizer](https://github.com/AndrewKeepCoding/WinUI3Localizer). It works for both packaged an unpackaged apps.